# What exactly can be considered a base game?

Tags: terminology

I'm kind of new to gaming and I am somewhat confused about all the terminology regarding to types of video game releases. I would appereciate if anyone can clarify somethings for me.

As I understand it, DLCs are additional content for the "base game", but what can exactly be considered the **base game**? I know the obvious one which is the standard edition of the game! But what I want to know is whether an alternative version such as remastered version or a ported version (e.g. Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare and its mobile or Nintendo ports) or even the special editions of the game can be considered a base game as well?

Is there any other term to refer to the base game?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The ***base game*** is usually the first complete released piece of content.
It is also referred to at times as '**vanilla**', as in the unflavoured or basic flavoured version, but - as isanae rightly points out in the comments - this term is mostly used to set a game with or without any officially released content apart from a modded version.
In some instances you can already get versions of a game which include additional and/or exclusive content (presented with cool names like Gold Edition, or Collector's Edition, the latter of which often features additional physical trinkets), or will include future content (which is often available separately as well).

All DLC also often comes in the form of a so-called ***Season Pass***.

Newer releases can include more of the content that has been released in the mean time, like all DLC. For example, when a game has been selected as Game of the Year, it is usually rereleased in a Game of the Year or GOTY edition, and, as far as I know, always includes all DLC/the Season Pass.
Sets including all available content from the get-go can be released as Ultimate Editions.

A ***remaster*** or Remastered Edition is a game that has been updated in one way or another. This is often a graphical update, where models or textures are of a higher fidelity or resolution, new graphical effects like Depth of Field, Ambient Occlusion, DLSS, or Ray Tracing have been implemented, or a game simply supports higher resolutions. But a remaster can also contain new or originally cut content, like how films have Director's Cuts.

Do note, however, that while they seem to adhere to a naming convention, editions with similar names do not always contain content you expect based on that convention.

***DLC*** is an abbreviation for **D**own**L**oadable **C**ontent.
It is usually used for a sizeable chunk of new content for the base game, offering a large new questline, a new significant piece of game world, new gameplay possibilities, and so on.

A game (or other piece of software) that was originally released on a specific platform (PC, PS, XBox, &c.) but later on (partially) rewritten and/or recoded for a different platform is called a ***port***.

A ***bundle*** is a relatively loose term: first and foremost I have to think about game bundles (e.g. the Humble Bundle) that offer a specific set or different tiers of games for certain price thresholds.
But a bundle can also be a base game bundled with certain DLC or less significant content (centred around a distinguishing theme, for example), or a combination of games from a particular series or IP.

Comment: thanks for the answer, now what about ports and remasters?

and are GOTY editions considered a bundle?

Comment: Often, you buy season passes prior to any DLC even being released for the game.  I personally don't really like them, because you pay for something upfront and have to wait before you get any value out of it, which for me, usually means I'm already bored of the game so it becomes a waste.  It has to be a game I really like for me to buy one!  The flip side is, you can always wait until DLC comes out, and then by the season pass (in most cases)

Comment: @Joachim thank you for update, i think i got my answer. just one more question if you don't mind. is a bundle and a video game compilation the same thing?

Comment: @Timmy Jim thanks, i understand that's what a port is, what i like to know is that why are some games are considered ports and they are literally a different game with a different title and at the same time some ports are just exactly the same. is there a distict terminology for these two types of ports!

Comment: I think _vanilla_ is more often used in the context of modding, not DLCs. You can have a full game, including DLCs, and play it vanilla or modded.

Comment: "this term is mostly used to **set a game apart from a modded version** (with or without any officially released content)." [it doesn't read well (especially after a shoutout to a commenter with an *insane* lowercase name) and it's missing a page break after]

Comment: @gamingNovice00 do you have an example of a port "that is a different game with a different title" than the game it's a port of?

Comment: A "port" with a different title that looks like a different game **is** a different game, and definitely not a port.

Comment: @pinckerman Yeap especially since port is actually not a game term but rather a software term with a specific meaning, of transforming the code base of a piece of software in such a way to be able to compile and run it on a different system.

Comment: @Josh Part Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare and it's wii & nintendo versions or Genma Onimusha are what comes to mind right now.

Comment: @pinckerman i agree but i think that would be called an **enhanced port** which is somewhat similar to a remaster and has additional content but a lot of ports are released under a different title with the same story but different gameplay or downgraded visuals which makes the experience very different. would you say Modern Warfare reflex edition is not a port? this game has been rebuilt from the ground up which raises the question **is this not basically a remake**?

Comment: I don't know that game, so I can't answer you

Comment: Remasters and ports can still be called "the base game", the term only has meaning relative to the context it's used in.  In contexts where someone is discussing DLC's, expansions, etc. then "base game" is whatever version of the game doesn't include them. In other contexts it may refer to the original release, a specific port, or probably a bunch of other things.

Answer (score 4):

**Base game** means each software product (in either digital or physical format) which does not include trial, premium content, or additional downloadable content. The "vanilla" version.

Remastered and ported versions are still considered "base game", as long as they have the same content of the original version. This means that they can't have premium content or DLCs that weren't included in the base version.
Of course, if the condensed port is a "lite" version with some missing feature, that's not considered base game either.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137677/discussion-on-answer-by-pinckerman-what-exactly-can-be-considered-a-base-game).

Answer (score 2):

In the context of DLC, the "base game" simply means "the game to which the DLC adds content". That's it. The provider of the DLC will indicate which game this is.